# DataTemplate overflows datagrid cell

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate

I have a little problem with the Datagrid. I am trying to implement an auto-complete textbox [As described [here](http://www.ageektrapped.com/blog/the-missing-net-3-an-autocomplete-textbox-in-wpf-part-1-a-rough-first-draft/)] in a DataGridCellTemplate. It is working perfectly so far, only problem is it overflows the assigned column space so it is made a lot bigger. I dont want this to happen, in other words, i want the listbox for the auto-complete entries to "float" over the datagrid, so it wont overflow the cell's assigned space. [I know its possible because i seen similar things before, so i think this is do-able].

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="LDary.Compras"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Compras" Height="300" Width="300" Name="WinCompras">
<Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding ElementName=WinCompras, Path=AutoCSource}" x:Key="Source" Filter="CollectionViewSource_Filter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Articulos de la compra:" Padding="0,2"/>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="Lista" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=WinCompras, Path=CompraActual}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Nombre" x:Name="Nombre">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Nombre}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" Loaded="TextBox_Loaded" Unloaded="TextBox_Unloaded"/>
                            <ListBox Visibility="Hidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Source}}" 
                                     Focusable="False" Loaded="ListBox_Loaded" Unloaded="ListBox_Unloaded">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nombre}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Name="BtnGuardar" Content="Guardar" Padding="0,5" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Button Name="BtnReset" Content="Reiniciar" Padding="0,5" Grid.Row="3" />
</Grid>
</Window >
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Popup` to avoid increasing the size of the cell when the completions are visible.  Here's a tutorial:

- [WPF Popup](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFPopup08172008075339AM/WPFPopup.aspx)

Comment: I tried wrapping the LB in a Popup but it didnt work as nothing as shown. Maybe i needed to configure something? Ill check your link. Thanks. EDIT: Setting it's IsOpen property to true did it :) I want to bind IsOpen to the Listbox visibility if possible :p

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot man, now i need to decipher why the row becomes read-only when i assign the auto-completed item to the ItemsSource bound collection :S